# 18.04 Server: Change WiFi frequency to 2.4Ghz band on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: networking, wireless, raspberrypi

I have 2.4GHz-only APs but my [Raspberry Pi 3B](http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_3_Model_B_Plus#Specification)+ has dual band capability. I want to tell Ubuntu in its terminal to make sure nothing runs on 5.2Ghz.

I have searched far and wide locally and on the internet for a solution to this, and have come back with nothing.

[3B+ specifications](http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_3_Model_B_Plus#Specification)

SoC: Broadcom BCM2837B0 quad-core A53 (ARMv8) 64-bit @ 1.4GHz

GPU: Broadcom Videocore-IV

RAM: 1GB LPDDR2 SDRAM

Networking: 2.4GHz and 5GHz 802.11b/g/n/ac Wi-Fi

Bluetooth: Bluetooth 4.2, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nmcli.html) is the CLI tool to use here to [control Network Manager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/nmcli.1.html).  As per https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections make sure your WiFi radio is on with `nmcli r wifi on` then find the name of your Pi's WiFi with `nmcli d`  .

List the WiFi Access Points (WAPs) with `nmcli d wifi list` then connect with `nmcli d wifi connect` *my_wifi* `password`   .

Since your WAPs are 2.4GHz, you won't select any 5 GHz WAP, and once you've connected to your 2.4 GHz WAP, it will stay connected.

[wpa_supplicant](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/wpa_supplicant.8.html) allows you to [specify frequencies](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) restricted to the [2.4 GHz band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#2.4_GHz_(802.11b/g/n/ax)) only by adding a file /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf with a line including

> freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up/5 provides GUI-based instructions if you've added a GUI to your server; https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXxHL.png shows the critical screen for WAP selection.

Comment: They will have different names *if* you rename them in the administration pages of the router!

Comment: On dual-band APs it is possible to use the same SSID ("name") and password on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz. Some AP vendors even recommend this and/or set it up that way by default.

Comment: Restriction method added above. Knew there was once, had to dig for it.